# Regex pattern expression missing variations

Tags: regex

I want to filter the following strings (w/o quotes):

- `'VISTA'`  <-- case doesn't matter here, can be VISTA, Vista, vista, visTA
- `'1+'`
- `'1 +'`

But not variations like

- `'Vaddx'`
- `'Aista'`
- `'1  +'`
- `'1'`
- `'1++'`
- `'+1'`

and so on

I'm using the following pattern for match, but I think something is missing.

```
 [VvIiSsTtAa]|1\\s\\+|1\\+
```

and the code bellow for test.

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string[] paymentType = new string[] {"VISTA", "vista", "Vista", "vtid", "1", "1+", "1  +", "+", "+1", "1++"};

        foreach (var item in paymentType)
        {
            Console.Write($"Item {item} is ");

            if(!Regex.Match(item, "[VvIiSsTtAa]|1\\s\\+|1\\+").Success)
               Console.Write("not ");
            Console.WriteLine("valid.");
        }

        Console.WriteLine("\n\n\n");
    }
```

What I've got is:

```
- Item VISTA is valid
- Item vista is valid
- Item Vista is valid
- Item vtid is valid   <<---- WRONG
- Item 1 is not valid
- Item 1+ is valid
- Item 1  + is not valid
- Item + is not valid
- Item +1 is not válid
- Item 1++ is valid  <<---- WRONG
```

What is missing in my patter string?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `[VvIiSsTtAa]` will match *any* combination of the letters in `vista`. You can either use `[Vv][Ii][Ss][Tt][Aa]` or change your regex to be case-insensitive and just use `vista`

Comment: Check https://ideone.com/H5EFnR

Comment: `^[Vv][Ii][Ss][Tt][Aa]$|^1\s?\+$` should work

Comment: Not a duplicate of a **_Reference_** !!

Answer (score 1):

This is the simple approach, where *`(?i)`* stands for case insensitive:

`(?i)^(vista|1[ ]?\+)$`

Assumes boundary are the string anchors.